# Two different google APIs on the same page

Tags: javascript, google-api

Is it possible to get two different javascript Google APIs to work on the same page? My goal is to use the autocomplete Google API to get an address to pass into the calculate distance API, allowing the user to autocomplete their address and immediately see the estimated travel time to a predefined location (similar to Uber). I am new to javascript, so I am not sure if there is some trick to solve this problem; any advice?

Answer (score 0):

If the question is "is it possible ?", I could just answer "yes" :).

You can insert autocomplete in HTML that will lead subsequent call to distance API, no problem.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I tried moving the autocomplete API script into the HTML and the distance API script outside of HTML but it makes no difference. The distance API loads first then the autocomplete API does not work at all. I noticed that the autocomplete API will not work when the google API key script for the distance API (below) is anywhere on the same page.  <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyPersonalKey&callback=initMap">
    </script>